Installing Liberica NIK
Following the Linux 64 .deb installation instructions at:
Liberica NIK Install Guide
it states running the following once the .deb has been unpacked:
$NIK_HOME/bin/gu available

and I get an error because "gu" is not found:
$ /opt/bellsoft/liberica-vm-core-23.1.3-openjdk21/bin/gu available
bash: /opt/bellsoft/liberica-vm-core-23.1.3-openjdk21/bin/gu: No such file or directory

In the specified /bin folder I do not see anything named "gu".
